# C++14 variable template with default template parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, variables, c++14

C++14 will allow variable templates:

```
template <typename T> constexpr T pi = T(3.1415926535897932385);
```

Now consider the following case:

```
template <typename T = double> constexpr T pi = T(3.1415926535897932385);
```

Question: how do I get `pi` with the default parameter ?

```
pi; // Option 1 (I hope...)
pi<>; // Option 2
```

Comment: I would assume option 2, since that's how it works for old-school templates. But I haven't looked at C++14 in that much detail yet.

Comment: The reason why `<>` needs to be avoided for function templates is so that you can select from an overload set which contains both templates and non-templates, e.g. `void foo(int); template<class T> void foo(T); foo(2.5);` It's necessary neither for class nor for variable templates -- that doesn't imply it won't be allowed. Looking into the current draft (github repo 8e1913d3), it looks like option 2 will have to be used.

Comment: and lastest clang that have it implemented compile only option 2. It says 1 is not allowed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on [n3651](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3651.pdf) I would say `pi<>;`. In the current standard template argument deduction, which being able to do `pi` is a form of, only applies to functions. Since the paper mentions absolutely nothing about TAD it is unlikely they would use it.

Comment: What does TAD stand for?

Comment: @Hector template argument deduction

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3651.pdf) draft the usage will be `pi<TYPE>` but this might change in time. with just `pi` the compiler might not be able to deduce type of `pi` just like writing a function like this: `template <class T> void foo();` and using like this: `foo()`

For default argument it should behave just like a function so it should be `pi;`